# доступ к настройкам микрофона в браузере

Tags: javascript

Пользуюсь апи `MediaRecorder`. Необходимо при нажатии клавиши определять дан ли доступ к микрофону на странице и, если нет, выдавать поп-ап с ошибкой. Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяем есть ли MediaRecorder в браузере:

```
if ('MediaRecorder' in window) {
    startRecord();
} else {
// Ошибка. Вывести на экран
}

function startRecord()
{
try {
          const stream = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: false
          });
          console.log(stream);

          mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
          mediaRecorder.onerror = (e) => {
             log('Error: ' + e);
             console.log('Error: ', e);
         };
         .....
         mediaRecorder.start();
} catch {
          // Выводим ошибку куда хотим
          console.log('You denied access to the microphone.');
}

.....
.....
}
```

Comment: спасибо. `onerror` то что я искал как раз